# Why is the limit the product, but not the coproduct?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

On page 489 of *Algebra*, Paolo gives an example of a limit:

Let $I$ be the discrete category with 2 objects with only identity morphisms, let $\alpha$ be a functor from $I$ to any category $C$, and let $A_1=\alpha(1), A_2=\alpha(2)$, then the limit of $\alpha$ is the product of $A_1$ and $A_2$ in $C$.

My question is that, if the disjoint union of $A_1,A_2$ exists in $C$, then why can’t we take it to be the limit, with the morphisms required by the limit to be the selection of elements of certain indices in the disjoint union?

Comment: Well, what would be the maps $A_1\times A_2\to A_1$ and $A_1\times A_2\to A_2$ which are required by the limit formulation? (Actually, a better question: how are you defining the disjoint union if $C$ is an arbitrary category, if not as the coproduct?)

Comment: It might be possible that the products in categories are a little special and the projection morphisms must exist for them, while the morphism for disjoint unions might not exist? I need some help.

Comment: You are treating the objects of $C$ as sets. That's the first issue. Second, even if you only deal with concrete categories (ones with set-like objects), there isn't a natural way to map $A_1\sqcup A_2\to A_1$. Like, if $A_1=\{1\}$ and $A_2=\{2,3\}$, what do you map $1$ to in the mapping $A_1\sqcup A_2\to A_2$?

Comment: @DonThousand Can’t I just simply not take it in the domain?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @DonThousand like, we let f be a morphism such that it maps {1,2},{1,3} to 2 and 3 in {2,3}, while it doesn’t include {0,1} in its domain.

Comment: @LeoGu Are partial maps permissible in the category you're considering? For example, $\mathcal {Set}$ is the category of sets and *total* functions. You could just as easily have sets and partial functions, but that would be a different category.

Comment: @LeoGu As S.C. says, there are categories in which partial functions as described could be allowed. But this doesn't work for $\textit{any}$ category, which is what Paolo is using in this statement. Unless you explain how this works for all categories, this is not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Paolo is saying that by definition, this limit is the product. In principle, the limit could be naturally isomorphic to the coproduct (and indeed, in the case of Abelian categories like the category of Abelian groups, this is exactly what happens).

Let's recall that the definition of the limit of a diagram $F : I \to C$ is some object $X \in C$, together with a natural transformation $\pi : \Delta X \to F$, such that for any object $Y \in C$ and any natural transformations $\tau : \Delta Y \to F$, there exists a unique $f : Y \to X$ such that $\tau = \pi \circ \Delta f$. Here, $\Delta : C \to C^I$ is the diagonal functor.

Now, we should unpack this definition. A natural transformation $\pi : \Delta X \to \alpha$ consists of an arrow $\pi_1 : (\Delta X)(1) \to \alpha(1)$ and an arrow $\pi_2 : (\Delta X)(2) \to \alpha(2)$ - that is, an arrow $\pi_1 : X \to A_1$ and another arrow $\pi_2 : X \to A_2$. So the limit of $\alpha$ is an object $X \in C$, together with arrows $\pi_1 : X \to A_1$ and $\pi_2 : X \to A_2$, such that for all $Y \in C$, for all arrows $\tau_1 : Y \to A_1$ and $\tau_2 : Y \to A_2$, there is a unique $f : Y \to X$ such that $\tau_1 = f \circ \pi_1$ and $\tau_2 = f \circ \pi_2$.

But the above is exactly the definition of the product of $A_1$ and $A_2$.